# Software for computing equivariants

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, invariant-theory, computer-algebra

If $\Gamma$ is a finite group with action on two vector spaces $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ denoted by $\gamma_n$ and $\gamma_m$ respectively, the fundamental equivariants are the polynomials $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ that commute with $\Gamma$, i.e. $$\gamma_m \cdot f(x) = f(\gamma_n^{-1} \cdot x) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^n.$$

It it well known that this set is a finitely generated free module over the ring of primary invariants.

**Is there any software available to compute a set of generators of the module of equivariants?**

An algorithm is described in page 12 of [this paper "Zeros of equivariant vector fields..."  by P. Worfolk (citeseerx link, unrestricted)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.41.6148&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for instance in pseudo code, but surprisingly I was not able to find any implementation online in Singular, Magma or similar.

Comment: I guess this set can be extracted from the set of generators of invariant ring (for which you have a choice of implementations) of the direct sum $\gamma_n\oplus\gamma_m$.

Comment: True, but that seems like a waste since that would correspond the projection of the invariants a small subspace. (subspace of polynomials that are linear in the new slack variables)

Comment: Have you tried googling https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=software+available+to+compute+a+set+of+generators+of+the+module+of+equivariants&ei=GrSyWu7WHYm6sQH-p4KgDw&start=0&sa=N&biw=1280&bih=888 ?

Comment: typically one would first compute the primary invariants, and you need them anyway. In practice these computations a very hard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical reference appears to be Karin Gatermann's book:

*Gatermann, Karin*, [**Computer algebra methods for equivariant dynamical systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0104059), Lecture Notes in Mathematics. 1728. Berlin: Springer. xv, 153 p. (2000). [ZBL0944.65131](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0944.65131).

In the book she frequently alludes to the *Maple* package *symmetry* which she uses to compute invariants and equivariants.

Comment: Thanks, that is "almost" perfect. The only issue is that Maple is not free. Do you know of any alternative?